# How to import images and body from external source via rss feed?

Tags: feeds

I am have some difficulty importing content from an rss feed provided by an external Drupal site call Parent Info. Subject to registration, the rss content is free to use under Creative Commons. I want to import the content for re-publication on a school website.

I've been using the news aggregator which is bundled with [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) and I have tried creating my own feed importer. This creating nodes as it should and importing the description, but I can't get it to to import the node body or images.

I guess this is about field mapping, but I can't see how to add a field for the images (for example)

The feed url is http://feed.parentinfo.org/articles/primary/rss/8118

I have tried most of the various options provided by the feed importer and have a working demo based on the Drupal Planet rss feed.

What am I doing wrong? And what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you could show us your a screenshot of your mapping that would help.

Comment: right off the bat, since the images are inside this weird <enclosure/> tag you will need to use feeds [Xpath Parser](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser)  here is an example of how to target https://www.drupal.org/node/1045026